# How to change the CSS class of a parent element if the child contains certain string chain

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm really new at this and I'm making my first question. So I've made a newsletter based website in Wordpress with Campaign Monitor integrated.

The below script displays basic HTML, a `ul` with some `li` elements that have an anchor inside, like this example:

```
...

<ul>
  <li><a href="http://example.createsend.com/t/ViewEmailArchive/t/">First Newsletter Title</a>, 11 December 2020</li>
  <li><a href="http://example.createsend.com/t/ViewEmailArchive/t/">Second Newsletter Title</a>, 12 December 2020</li>
  <li><a href="http://example.createsend.com/t/ViewEmailArchive/t/">Third Newsletter Title</a>, 13 December 2020</li>
</ul>

...
```

So I made my shot by trying to use JavaScript to make a function that:

- Selects the anchor tags that contain a certain string (for this example we could use the keyword 'First').
- Then changes, toggles or adds a CSS class to hide or `display: none` the **li** elements that do not contain the keyword.

Like I said I'm a newbie in JavaScript and am working with Wordpress so to achieve this I added a text editor and in there I wrote my function, that looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a:contains(First)').closest('li').addClass('hide');
});
```

As you can probably see, I am trying to add the `hide` CSS class to the anchors that contain the keyword 'First' however, **this is not working at all**. So I wondered what could be wrong and if **someone thinks of a better idea or a solution to fix my function.**

Comment: First thing to know: java and javascript are NOT the same

Comment: Your code works fine. Do you have jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not worked with jquery for a while and I don't know how the `$("a:contains(First)")` works but the snippet below works as you described

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("a").each(function () {
      if ($(this).text().indexOf("First") !== -1) {
        console.log($(this).text());  
        $(this).closest("li").addClass("hidden");
      }
      
    }) 
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://example.createsend.com/t/ViewEmailArchive/t/">First Newsletter Title</a>, 11 December 2020</li>
  <li><a href="http://example.createsend.com/t/ViewEmailArchive/t/">Second Newsletter Title</a>, 12 December 2020</li>
  <li><a href="http://example.createsend.com/t/ViewEmailArchive/t/">Third Newsletter Title</a>, 13 December 2020</li>
</ul>
```

Basically I iterated trough all the elements and checked if the text contains the word: "First".

Comment: Oh yeah I see, that's exactly what I'm aiming for, I think I just don't know how to implement it in a wordpress page, because it's still not working there

Comment: Ok, So I managed to get this function to work on my site now! now I'm having the blank spaces from the li and as far as I know, the css display:none totally removes the visibiilty and "space" that the element uses so I think if I set some subtle delay before starting it could work better for me and wont leave the blank spaces. Do you know how to apply that to your function?

Comment: Did you managed to fix this issue? I think your ul and li has some css which sets the position of the li elements to be fixed. If you still have the issue can you post the css which is applied to the ul and li?